# picasso image rotation issue in android 10 using Uri of image

Tags: android, picasso, android-10.0

Picasso has an image rotation issue when showing it in android 10 using Uri of image

```
Uri uri = "content://media/external/images/media/12155";
Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageView);
```

I'm used the last version 2.8

[image: Roation issue]

this is the original image

[image: original image]

this issue not found if android API 28 for example the issue happened with greater than or equals to android 29

Comment: What's the issue? Like, it rotates the image automatically? Are you sure the original is not actually like that? Sometimes we take photos in portrait mode with the phone sideways and think we're taking a landscape photo.

Comment: this is the original photo https://i.ibb.co/QJjHBY1/IMG-20210503-090344.jpg 
when I show the image in android 28 its work with the original orientation

Comment: And if you are using this in an emulator are the settings for landscape/portrait the same as your Android 8 device? Asking because it's the only thing I can think of. I never heard anything like this dependent on Picasso

Comment: try this image 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_VFpwrp3o6ZVUe7YmHcIDtF1PYI19NFz/view?usp=sharing

in the android 29 and remove this flag from manifests
requestLegacyExternalStorage=true

Comment: @Fred Also note that when I show the same image with Glide library it's shown without problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class solve the issue

https://daniel.perez.sh/blog/2015/image-orientation-picasso/

```
package com.example.util;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public class ExifTransformation implements Transformation {
    private static final String[] CONTENT_ORIENTATION = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION
    };

    final Context context;
    final Uri uri;

    public ExifTransformation(Context context, Uri uri) {
        this.context = context;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) return source;

        int exifRotation = getExifOrientation(context, uri);
        if (exifRotation != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preRotate(exifRotation);

            Bitmap rotated =
                    Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            if (rotated != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }
            return rotated;
        }

        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) return "documentTransform()";
        return "documentExifTransform(" + uri.toString() + ")";
    }

    public static int getExifOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri, CONTENT_ORIENTATION, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }
}
```

When loading the image, the following then gave the wanted result:

```
Picasso
    .with(this)
    .load(uri)
    .transform(new ExifTransformation(this, uri))
    .into(imageView);
```